# VB.NET WebClient Proxy Not Connecting To Google

Tags: vb.net, proxy, webclient, proxies

**I'm working on a small application that can query google from the WebClient class in VB.NET. I noticed that the WebClient queries Google just fine without the proxy property being added, but I'd like to also have the capability of using proxies to connect to Google as well and it just isn't working. Here's the code that I have:**

```
Try
        Dim wc As New System.Net.WebClient()
'This line below will bring in the "User Agent" to make the HTTP request:
        wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36")

        Dim wp As New System.Net.WebProxy(TextBox1.Text)
        wc.Proxy = wp
        Dim HTML As String = wc.DownloadString("https://www.google.com/search?q=spider+man")
        TextBox1.Text = HTML
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

The problem is that NOTHING comes back even though I know that I'm using an ALIVE proxy (working public proxy) as it's connects through other browser applications perfectly to Google. Some how Google is blocking my application because it's apparently missing something. I have the headers setup correctly, so I know it can't be that (or at least I believe that I have them setup correctly).

Would appreciate any support.

Comment: I keep getting the following error messages, either:

"Unable to connect to the remote server"

OR

"The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable."

What am I missing to connect to google using a proxy with the WebClient?

Comment: please read this...seems like it is related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405095/problem-with-httpwebrequest-503

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but this isn't resolving my issue because there's not clarity with how he's implementing the proper proxy into the WebClient class in VB.NET. His code was totally different than mine & the other guy was using the httpWebRequest class instead of the WebClient class. It's like Google is detecting that I'm connecting through a proxy but without the proper headers or something more. Not sure what it is though.